# Substituição de caracteres em tabelas SQl Server

Tags: sql-server, tsql, replace

Preciso fazer um replace de algumas cadeias de caracteres em um banco.

ESTOU TENTANDO COM:

```
UPDATE dbo.ModeloMensagem
SET corpoMensagem = REPLACE(dbo.ModeloMensagem.corpoMensagem, '<', '[')
WHERE dbo.ModeloMensagem.corpoMensagem IN (SELECT DISTINCT(dbo.CampoTipoMensagem.nome) FROM dbo.CampoTipoMensagem);

UPDATE dbo.ModeloMensagem
SET corpoMensagem = REPLACE(dbo.ModeloMensagem.corpoMensagem, '>', ']')
WHERE dbo.ModeloMensagem.corpoMensagem IN (SELECT DISTINCT(dbo.CampoTipoMensagem.nome) FROM dbo.CampoTipoMensagem);


--DEPOIS ATUALIZA TABELA CampoTipoMensagem
UPDATE dbo.CampoTipoMensagem
SET nome = REPLACE(dbo.CampoTipoMensagem.nome, '<', '[');

UPDATE dbo.CampoTipoMensagem
SET nome = REPLACE(dbo.CampoTipoMensagem.nome, '>', ']');
```

Dentro da tabela `CampoTipoMensagem` existem algumas tags ex:, , etc...
Mas existem algumas tags HTML também. Preciso substituir essas tags do exemplo (existem mais) por [CPF_CANDIDATO] (por exemplo).

Alguém aqui conhece a solução para isso?
Se eu rodar o `replace`, ele vai alterar até as tags HTML.

Comment: @rLinhares eu não entendi, esse update ele está substituindo corretamente a tag < por [ ? Você quer q altere < por [CPF_CANDIDATO]? Se sim, não seria o caso de Replace('<', '[CPF_CANDIDATO]') ?

Comment: transfiro a pergunta para @Daniel Chagas :p

Comment: As mensagens estão assim: <ID-CANDIDATO> (exemplo). Existem também algumas tags HTML na mensagem. Ou seja, no campo corpoMensagem existe uma mensagem com caracteres de A-Z, tags HTML e essas do exemplo. Eu tenho que substituir só os <> das mensagens do exemplo. As tags HTML tem que continuar...

Comment: Pessoal, problema resolvido...

A solução não coube aqui.